# struts validation using xml

Tags: java, xml, validation, struts2

This is my Action class

```
public class DoctorsController extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Doctor> {

private DoctorDao docDao = new DoctorDaoImpl();
private List<Doctor> listDoc = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
 private Doctor doc = new Doctor();

public List<Doctor> getListDoc() {
    return listDoc;
}

public void setListDoc(List<Doctor> listDoc) {
    this.listDoc = listDoc;
}


public String excute() throws Exception {
    return SUCCESS;

}

public String getDoctorView() {

    return SUCCESS;
}

public Doctor getDoc() {
    return doc;
}

public void setDoc(Doctor doc) {
    this.doc = doc;
}



public String addDoctor() {

    this.docDao.addDoctor(this.doc);
    listDoc = docDao.listDoctor();
    return SUCCESS;

}

@Override
public Doctor getModel() {
    return doc;
}

public DoctorDao getDocDao() {
    return docDao;
}

public void setDocDao(DoctorDao docDao) {
    this.docDao = docDao;
}
```

}

this is my form to persist a doctor in database

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <s:form action="saveDoctor" method="post">
        <table>  
            <s:push value="doc">
                <s:hidden name="id"  />

                <s:textfield name="firstName" label="First Name" />

                <s:textfield name="lastName" label="Last Name" />


                <s:textfield name="email" label="Email" />

                <s:textfield name="fees" label="Fees" />

        <s:select name="specialist" list="#@java.util.LinkedHashMap@{'Bone':'Bone','Heart':'Heart'}" />

                <s:textfield name="chamber.city" label="City" />

                 <s:textfield name="chamber.zipCode" label="ZipCode" />
                 <s:textfield name="chamber.roadNum" label="Road Num" />
                 <s:textfield name="chamber.houseNum" label="House Num" />




           <s:submit/>

            </table>     

            </s:push>
    </s:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my DoctorsController-validation.xml which is used to validate doctors email

```
<validators>
 <field name="doc.email">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">

        <message>Email can't be blank</message>

    </field-validator>

 </field>
</validators>
```

Now validation is working fine because if "email" field is empty action is redirected to input form but problem is i can't see any  validation message in my input form.I should see a message like "Email can't be blank " but i don't see it.

Comment: I assume you are using the defaul XHTML theme... does it work if you remove the `<s:push>` and put `doc.` in front of each `name="` attribute ? Please try

Comment: After removing `push` and putting `doc.` in front of each `name` remove model driven also. BTW you're not really using modeldriven right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <form name="doc">
       <field property="email" depends="required,email">
            <arg key="doc.email"/>
        </field>
        <field property="firstName" depends="required">
            <arg key="doc.firstName"/>
        </field>
    </form>
```

This code works for me .

Comment: The question is about S2.